# NSTextView – text disappears while adding a new line

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nstextview

I've recently met a problem that once I'm adding a new line in an NSTextView, the least visible line disappears for a moment. The same happens when I'm deleting a line.

The problem occurs even in a newly created Xcode project with pure NSTextView. Here is a quick preview (GIF):

[image: Bug Preview]

Here is the text I'm playing with (4 lines):

```
aa
```

Has anyone met this problem?

Comment: Is the issue reproducible in TextEdit?

Comment: No, it's not. Actually, I've found the problem and answered my question below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions is to set this `allowsNonContiguousLayout` of the LayoutManager to `false`, e.g.:

`textView.layoutManager.allowsNonContiguousLayout = false`